# What is the part of the bible that speaks about offering the traveler shelter when on the road/visiting other churches?

Tags: intertextuality

I'm trying to write an essay about only being a guest in the house of someone else as I'm getting big into writing, and public speaking.

What is the exact passage about traveling, and staying where you're wanted until asked to leave, as I'm bouncing it off the "authorities" in the life of a young woman, and his responsibility to protect his "daughters", along with how two people will become one flesh able to prove they can advocate for the other properly? I'm only wondering because "I am but a guest" who doesn't wish to wear out his welcome in his house (church).

Comment: I was gonna offer a comment...but I just can t get a handle on what this means? "the "authorities" in the life of a young woman, and his responsibility to protect his "daughters", along with how two people will become one flesh able to prove they can advocate for the other properly?" Also this is lacking a scripture to practice  hermeneutic on, so It is really not applicable here.

Comment: look up paul washer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJqE9qchGpo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you may be alluding to but here are a few:

- **Matt 10:9-15** - Do not carry any gold or silver or copper in your belts. Take no bag for the road, or second tunic, or sandals, or staff; for the worker is worthy of his provisions. Whatever town or village you enter, find out who is worthy there and stay at his house until you move on. As you enter the house, greet its occupants. If the home is worthy, let your peace rest on it; if it is not, let your peace return to you. And if anyone will not welcome you or heed your words, shake the dust off your feet when you leave that home or town. Truly I tell you, it will be more bearable for Sodom and Gomorrah on the day of judgment than for that town.
- **Luke 10:5-12** - Whatever house you enter, begin by saying, ‘Peace to this house.’ If a man of peace is there, your peace will rest on him; if not, it will return to you. 7Stay at the same house, eating and drinking whatever you are offered. For the worker is worthy of his wages. Do not move around from house to house. If you enter a town and they welcome you, eat whatever is set before you. 9Heal the sick who are there and tell them, ‘The kingdom of God is near you.’ But if you enter a town and they do not receive you, go into the streets and declare, ‘Even the dust of your town that clings to our feet, we wipe off as a testimony against you. Yet be sure of this: The kingdom of God is near.’ I tell you, it will be more bearable on that day for Sodom than for that town.
- **1 Tim 5:18** - For Scripture says, "Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain," [Deut 25:4] and "The worker deserves his wages."
- **1 Cor 9:4-11** - Have we no right to food and to drink? Have we no right to take along a believing wife, as do the other apostles and the Lord’s brothers and Cephas? Or are Barnabas and I the only apostles who must work for a living? Who serves as a soldier at his own expense? Who plants a vineyard and does not eat of its fruit? Who tends a flock and does not drink of its milk? Do I say this from a human perspective? Doesn’t the Law say the same thing? For it is written in the Law of Moses: “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain.” Is it about oxen that God is concerned? Isn’t He actually speaking on our behalf? Indeed, this was written for us, because when the plowman plows and the thresher threshes, they should also expect to share in the harvest. If we have sown spiritual seed among you, is it too much for us to reap a material harvest from you?